# Mac OS - How to programmatically detect the Mac user (logged in user) is admin using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, admin, appkit

I want to detect the role of the user (Admin / Standard). I have to show a popup on the Mac application based on that Role.

Is there any Cocoa API in Objective-C to identify this?

We can check the role in Systerm Preferences under Users & Groups like below.

Standard User
[image]

Admin User
[image]

I can able to get the root permission using `getuid()` from `<unistd>`.
But that doesn't help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to use the CoreServices framework and its [Identity Services](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/os_services/identity_services?language=objc) tools.

You can get an reference to the identity of the current user with `CSIdentityQueryCreateForCurrentUser`:

```c
CSIdentityRef currentUserIdentity(CFErrorRef *error) {
    CSIdentityQueryRef const query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForCurrentUser(NULL);
    if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(query, 0 /* flags, none needed */, error)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFArrayRef const users = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(query);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(users) != 1) {
        // TODO: set `*error`
        return NULL;
    }

    return (CSIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(users, 0);
}
```

You can similarly create a query for the "admin" group (note all lowercase):

```c
CSIdentityRef adminGroupIdentity(CFErrorRef *error) {
    CSIdentityQueryRef const query = CSIdentityQueryCreateForName(NULL, CFSTR("admin"), kCSIdentityQueryStringEquals, kCSIdentityClassGroup, CSGetDefaultIdentityAuthority());
    if (!CSIdentityQueryExecute(query, 0 /* flags, none needed */, error)) {
        return NULL;
    }

    CFArrayRef const groups = CSIdentityQueryCopyResults(query);
    if (CFArrayGetCount(groups) != 1) {
        // TODO: Set `*error`
        return NULL;
    }

    return (CSIdentityRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(groups, 0);
}
```

Checking for identity membership is then as simple as checking `CSIdentityIsMemberOfGroup`:

```c
CFErrorRef error = nil;
CSIdentityRef const currentUser = currentUserIdentity(&error);
if (!currentUser) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get current user: %@", error);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

CSIdentityRef const adminGroup = adminGroupIdentity(&error);
if (!adminGroup) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to get admin group: %@", error);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

NSLog(@"%@ is %@: %hhu", CSIdentityGetPosixName(currentUser), CSIdentityGetPosixName(adminGroup), CSIdentityIsMemberOfGroup(currentUser, adminGroup));
```

Comment: Thanks. It is pretty good API. This is what exactly I

Comment: @ShanmugarajaG Note that I wrote the above samples with ARC in mind — if you're doing manual reference counting in your code, you'll need to adapt the above to avoid memory leaks.